# How to pass additional information using auth0-js (to redirect the user after login)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

I would like to redirect the user to the current page where he was before the login workflow.

1. the user wants to go to /profile
2. the page is protected; the user is redirected to /login
3. log in workflow with auth0-js that redirect to /callback
4. I would like the callback page to redirect the user to the /profile page

Is there any possibilities to pass additional information to auth0-js (e.g. `{from: '/profile'}`)?

Here is my initialization of Auth0-js in my react app:

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
        domain: 'xxx.auth0.com',
        clientID: 'xxx',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
        audience: 'https://xxx.auth0.com/userinfo',
        responseType: 'token id_token',
        scope: 'openid profile offline_access'
    });
```

To log the user:

```
auth0.authorize();
```

I couldn't find way to do this without storing in the localStorage the information.

Comment: I just checked for you. You need to use the params object:

      { redirectUrl: 'xxx',params: {
        state: statePath /* the path to the url you want to redirect to on login */
      } }

And then on successful callback, you can use that to location.href to this state :-) As it will be part of your authResult object.

Comment: I understood that the 'params' is only available using auth0-lock (not auth0-js). I don't have any 'params' property available.

Comment: So if no replacement is available for the params setting, you are left with the localStorage option which you are already using. The only other option would be to use the pop-up style login. That one doesn't leave the page so you still have the current state of your application available. It's harder to implement though. Look for: webAuth.popup

Comment: State should not be used as a redirect, auth0-js' `authorize` endpoing will accept a state however, this should be a dynamic value instead of static url. Please read more about this at https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclosure: I work for Auth0.

Your application *should not* accept an arbitrary parameter in the callback and use it to redirect the user forward. I would recommend storing the information in *localStorage* and referencing it with a unique hash such as `state`.

For example

```
const state = getRandomBytes(32); // Assume that  this method will give you 32 bytes

localStorage[state] = { pathToGotoAfterAuth: '/somepath' };

auth0.authorize({
   state: state
});


// Then later
const authResult = auth0.parseHash();
const state = authResult.state;
const olderAppState = localStorage[state];
localStorage.remove(state);
redirect(olderAppState.pathToGotoAfterAuth);
```

Then upon callback, you'll receive this state and your application can then perform necessary actions using the stored version.

This has several advantages such as

- Being resilient to CSRF attacks.
- If you were to want to restore more data in future this is trivial.

Comment: I read on the docs that state is not used to pass custom values but to minimize CSRF attack. I will use the localStorage (as I did now) but using the state value as a key. I named it 'redirectToUri' without any further checks and that was probably not the best idea. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect my exact recommendation :)

Comment: The "state" value is auto-generated; why specify another one?

Comment: I am trying to answer a more generic case. Consider if you have two tabs which are trying to do the auth parallely, you'll have them override each other's next endpoint.

Comment: const olderAppState = localStorage[state];
localStorage.remove(state);
redirect(olderAppState.pathToGotoAfterAuth)  < === Think need to parse olderAppState... as localStorage value will be in JSON String.